# Location on Meizu with react-native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, geolocation

I am trying to get user location by react-native.

```
import Permissions from 'react-native-permissions';
export default class GeoLocation {
        async getCurrentPosition() {
            const permission = await Permissions.check('location');
            if (permission === 'undetermined' || permission === 'denied') {
                await Permissions.request('location');
            }
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
                    position => resolve(position),
                    error => reject(error),
                    {
                        timeout: 20000,
                    },
                )
            })
        }
    }
```

On all phones it works good, but on Meizu it is always returns `timed out`. It was tested on three Meizu phones. What i have to do to make it works on Meizu?

I solved this problem by rebooting phones.

Comment: i got the same problem on cordova 8 and android 6 on meizu note m5, after reboot twice, the code was working, no more timeout. but sometimes it goes timeout again, so i have to reboot it.